# need to download software link for ibm mq explorer

Tags: ibm-mq

Can anyone share the ibm mq explorer software link, I am not getting the correct link.

Thanks

am not getting proper download link

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you typed or are using but if you put "ibm mq explorer" into Mr. Google then the first hit is "MS0T: IBM MQ Explorer". As noted in the SupportPac, IBM now provides MQ Explorer via [Fix Central](https://ibm.biz/mqexplorer).